# run a java program using -cp option and classpath in manifest file

Tags: java

I plan to run a java class like

```
java -cp myjar.jar MyClass
```

myjar.jar will have a manifest file with classpath entry in it.
Is it a valid use case? I have a doubt since I have only seen usage of manifest when using `java -jar myjar.jar`

Comment: I would just test it.... but *maybe* [How Classes are Found](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html) and documentation of [JAR](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/jar/jar.html) can help

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `-cp` (or the `CLASSPATH` enviromment variable) together with `-jar`.  If you need to specify a classpath to make an executable JAR file work, you can specify a `Class-Path` attribute in the JAR file's manifest.

On the other hand, the `Class-Path` attribute in a JAR file manifest is *only* used for classes loaded from the JAR file itself.  (But it is not restricted to use with `-jar` option.)

For more details, refer to the [JAR file specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/jar/jar.html) and [How classes are found](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html).